# Function in javascript applying only in one of the lines

Tags: javascript, html

I have this little table with 2 columns and 2 lines. I type manually a number in "Fuel" and should display the double on the column "Double_Fuel". Unfortunately it only applies my function for the first line. In the second line it is not working. Somebody knows why? Thanks in advance

[image]

```html
<html>

<body>

<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} </style>

<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->

<table id="MyTable" class="egt">


<! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
 
<tr>    
            <th>Fuel</th>
            <th>Double_Fuel</th>
</tr>
  
<! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->   

<tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" id="fuel"> 
     </td>  
    
     <td>
     <input type="number" ID="fuel2" >
     </td>   
</tr>

<! --TERCERA LINEA -->  

<tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" id="fuel"> 
     </td>  
    
     <td>
     <input type="number" ID="fuel2" >
     </td>   
</tr>



</table>


<script>
var fuel = document.getElementById('fuel');
var fuel2 = document.getElementById('fuel2');
function calculate(){
fuel2.value = Number(fuel.value)*2;
}
var inputElement = document.getElementById('fuel');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your ID's are not **unique** - so `var fuel = document.getElementById('fuel');` refers to the first such element likewise `var fuel2 = document.getElementById('fuel2');

Comment: duplicateidoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because you had duplicated the `IDs`, which must be unique on a single webpage.

So, I have changed the `IDs` to `classes` and used the `.querySelectorAll()` method and then add via a `forEach` loop the `.addEventListener()` method to all the possible `<input>` you could have in your `<table>` (for future support).

Here's the working code:

```html
<html>

<body>

<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} </style>

<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->

<table id="MyTable" class="egt">


<! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
 
<tr>    
            <th>Fuel</th>
            <th>Double_Fuel</th>
</tr>
  
<! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->   

<tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  
    
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   
</tr>

<! --TERCERA LINEA -->  

<tr> 
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel"> 
     </td>  
    
     <td>
     <input type="number" class="fuel2" >
     </td>   
</tr>



</table>


<script>
  
  var fuels = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel');
  
  fuels.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function() {
 this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.value = Number(this.value)*2;
    });
  });
  
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

ids should be unique on a page therefore `getElementById` returns only one element (or null if no matching id was found) but you can do the calculate function with the help of the dataset attributes and using classes instead of ids like so:

```js
function calculate() {
  const result = document.querySelector(`#${this.dataset.result}`);
  result.value = Number(this.value) * 2;
}

const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.fuel');
inputElements.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', calculate));
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->
<table id="MyTable" class="egt">
  <! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
  <tr>
    <th>Fuel</th>
    <th>Double_Fuel</th>
  </tr>
  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="fuel" data-result="fuel1">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fuel1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <! --TERCERA LINEA -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="fuel" data-result="fuel2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fuel2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var fuel = document.getElementById('fuel');
var fuel2 = document.getElementById('fuel2');

function calculate(elem) {
  document.getElementById('double-' + elem.target.id).value = Number(elem.target.value) * 2;
}
document.getElementById('fuel').addEventListener('change', calculate);
document.getElementById('fuel2').addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="MyTable" class="egt">
  <tr>
    <th>Fuel</th>
    <th>Double_Fuel</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fuel">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" ID="double-fuel">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fuel2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" ID="double-fuel2">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```